# UIActivityViewController sharing via SMS not accepting NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Trying to share a `NSAttributedString` string (contains embedded links) via SMS by using `UIActivityViewController`:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [linkToShare], applicationActivities: nil)                      

present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

`linkToShare` is of type `NSMutableAttributedString`

Unfortunately the text is shared but without the embedded links (and the words for the links are not highlighted). 
When sharing via the **Mail** activity the text appears as expected (worded links are highlighted and links are working).

Does the SMS activity works with attributed string or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The SMS activity does work with `NSAttributedString` in a sense that it compiles and does not crash. But as for the Mail activity, the attributed string has to be converted into a format suitable with the protocol ultimately used to transfer the message.

For the **Mail** activity, the attributed string can be converted into html which will keep the format of your string.

For **SMS**, plain text is the only possibility so that's why the attributes you set are ignored.

That said, some SMS clients will auto-detect links as the Message app does on iOS. In the end, the formatting of an SMS message depends more on the receiving client than on the sender.

Comment: In my the message is targeted for iOS users only. It seems odd that the native Message app won't support attributed strings (I am guessing it uses UITextView to display the text) while it supports other types of data. So from what I understand I should send the links as is (opposed to embedded links) right?